# Street Intersection Coordinates with HERE Geocoding and Search API v7

Tags: geocoding, latitude-longitude, here-api

Is it possible, with HERE Geocoding and Search API v7, to get the coordinates of the center of two intersecting streets? I've tried a number of things with no luck, and there's nothing in the documentation aside from a place category called "Named Intersection-Chowk" (which only seems to work with famous intersections and with specific endpoints).

The reason I ask is that with the old REST Geocoder API (which is no longer being actively developed), you can send the following GET request to obtain the latitude and longitude of two intersecting streets (in this case, W Fullerton Ave & N Halsted St in Chicago):

```
https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?apiKey=*****&city=Chicago&street=Fullerton%20%40%20Halsted
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the intersection the same way with the new API:

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY=Fullerton %26 Halsted chicago illinois
```

The access field is the closest location to the intersection, but it's not exactly in the middle:

```
"access": [
{
  "lat": 41.92545,
  "lng": -87.64925
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for the coordinates of the center of the intersection rather than the access point for the address closest to the intersection (which is what `https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY&q=Fullerton%26Halsted+chicago+illinois` provides).